# Can the "Vote to close" button be placed more conveniently in the popup in the mobile layout?

Tags: feature-request, review, design, vote-to-close, mobile-web

When a question received close votes for being a duplicate and one also casts a close vote for that reason, previously suggested duplicates can be selected.

That's convenient. The preview of the duplicate is expanded to show the entire question and all answers, which helps reviewing this possible duplicate.

The big amount of additionally displayed content pushes the submit button very far down. It's often sufficient to read the other question or a few answers to decide if it is indeed a duplicate.

All the convenience of being able to click on a previous suggestion is eliminated by the need to scroll *all the way* down to the bottom of the pop-up in order to click on the submit button.

Some possible solutions I could think of:

- position the button near the top
- create multiple buttons and place one below the question and every answer
- move the button along when scrolling the window
- keep the height of the popup constant and let the content of the question expand in its own scrollable environment

Comment: In addition to moving the button to the top of the screen, I would also ask to include some sort of personal "favourite" questions I can pick from. I guess that like 8 out of 10 duplicates I put down go to the very same original question. But the damn search wont find them. Sometimes they show up in the auto list, most often, they don't. Let me put my favourites there, problem solved!